# Random number generators to work on x86_64

Tags: python, random, cython, gsl

This question is about using the GNU Scientific Library's random number generators in Cython (under Python 3.2) on a Mac OSX 10.7 (Lion) system.

Since Lion is a 64-bit OS, the installer gave me a 64-bit version of Python. I have successfully installed Cython (v0.15.1) and numpy (v1.6.1).

I want to replicate Flavio Coelho's example from [here](http://pyinsci.blogspot.com/2010/12/efficcient-mcmc-in-python.html), using C libraries to get the "Python" code to run at C speed. It seems that the way Flavio uses the Gnu Scientific Library's random number generator does not work (for me!) in a 64-bit environment. Here is the error message that I get during compilation (actually, I think it arises after compilation, during linking, but I am no expert in C):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gsl_rng_mt19937", referenced from:
      _PyInit_cgibbs in cgibbs.o
  "_gsl_rng_alloc", referenced from:
      _PyInit_cgibbs in cgibbs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: BTW: my C compiler is gcc-4.2.

Comment: I downloaded GSL from `www.gnu.org/s/gsl` and then did `./configure --disable-shared`, `make`, `make install`.

Comment: Are you sure you compiled GSL for x86_64 and not ordinary x86?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it was compiled on a x86_64 system, so it would seem natural that it compiled for x86_64.

Comment: You have a lot of components there.  It's often very difficult to build them all separately yourself from source to be mutually compatible.  Suggest you save yourself lots of headaches, short-term and long-term, by deleting the components you installed and installing everything using one package manager, like MacPorts or homebrew.

Comment: I can see the allure of that, Ned, but I think I would be setting myself up for long-term headaches that way. In my experience, there's a lot of software with caveats against using MacPorts' Python. Homebrew I might look at.

Comment: Can you paste the compilation line please ? Otherwise, try to use otool for ensuring that the libraries generated is for x86_64, and that the library is accessible from all the -L passed to the compilation line.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling you should add -lgsl prefix to link GSL library.